# Is it technically possible to block votes from a certain geographic area?

Tags: discussion, voting

I assume that such a functionality isn't implemented today. However, I'm curious if it's possible to do technically speaking, should a reason for it be found.

I'd like to be able to block votes from the proximity of our location, so that any reputation change originating within the room or building would be registered but disregarded.

The reason for such a unusual request is that I urge my students to actively participate in SO. In fact, I require (almost) for them to register and I refuse (almost) to solve their issue if I can find it on SO. (I do show how to find it there, of course.)

When they work on a project, it's natural that they post questions and sometimes I answer myself or ask a colleague to do that. That triggers the detection algorithm of SO which recently resulted in a suspension. In order to avoid that, I can stop urging people to register but I rather wouldn't.

Can someone suggest another approach to it (other than geo-block), I'd be delighted. At the moment, I can only imagine registering a separate accout to do that. But that **would really** be sock-puppetry.

Comment: "Is it technically possible" Oh, [absolutely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/a-number-of-duplicates-posted-in-the-last-hour-by-different-users/53807#53807).

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the right way to achieve your aim, honestly. However, maybe an appropriate solution would be to have your students self-answer their inquiries, instead of involving your colleagues or yourself. That way the conflict of interest would disappear and the same IP being used would not matter.

Comment: @BoltClock I want **that**!!!  :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'll make sure to consider a different approach. However, I fear that their answers will be far below par (seemingly correct but leading to baaad design) or that they simply get stuck and won't do it. Where I'm active, if the students fail, it's always the trainer's fault. (Sometimes it is, of course, but still...) Thanks for the input, mate.

Comment: @BoltClock As a side note - why on Earth did this got -5 rep?! I really getting an impression that it's my name that gets the bash not the formulation, hehehe. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I have tried ans it failed

Comment: @TariiqHenryBbosa What precisely did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Those university-wide bans are ... interesting. Did you just uncover the root cause of the crashing Tesla auto-piloted cars? Konrad, do you realize that such an IP ban would not only affect your students, but you as well ... and the students *next* door who are studying DNA chains and using Python for that, and the guys over at the other office who are trying to write a thesis and need [tex.se] and [maths.se] ... and the local Scifi fandom being robbed from [scifi.se]?

Comment: The downvotes are likely because people think this would be a bad idea to implement. It happens to a lot of posts on Meta, no matter who the author, even to Jeff Atwood himself. The votes almost certainly have nothing to do with you personally.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Maybe I'm simply oversensitive these days, hehe. This time of year or something. I'll try to get my crap together and man up a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just tell your students your SO account and your colleague and tell them not to up vote them.   Meta is different in that down vote can just mean disagree.

Comment: @Paparazzi I did, numerous times. It worked pretty well the last couple of years, in fact. However, all good things must come to an end and a few weeks ago, I got suspended. *You can **tell** 'em. But did they **hear**. They **heard** but did they **rememeber**.* You know the drill... I prefer to rely on an algorithm rather than people's attention.

Comment: @RadLexus Oh, sorry if I was unclear. I don't mean to ban the IP as such. As I wrote in the question - the votes might very well be registered **but** the gain of **my** reputation disabled **if** the vote comes from an IP near **me**. So they can vote on **anything** but the rep is affected only if the post comes from far away to me or if my pupils vote for far away posts.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You cannot expect SO to provide custom blocking or reputation.   I wonder if SO would tolerate you closing your answers with "For my students do not up vote this answer".   It may get edited out but I don't think you would face discipline for that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) when answering your students on Stack Overflow instead of in class:

> Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not
>   confer any reputation.

I'm assuming that since having an SO account is a requirement for your class that you already have a list of their account names, but it shouldn't be a big deal to get that.